# How much locations do sampler2D take?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Let's consider the following shader code:

```c
layout(location = 0) uniform sampler2D someTexture;
layout(location = ?) uniform int someInteger
```

How do I know what to replace the question mark with? How many locations does sampler2D take?

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  `sampler2D` uses `layout(binding = ?)` not `layout(location = ?)`.  Am I mistaken?  sampler2D is an opaque type and cannot be part of a buffer-backed interface block.

Comment: @Wyck: It's a uniform, and you can [specify the location of a uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Explicit_Uniform_Location), distinct from specifying the binding point for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All single variables of non-aggregate types take up a single `uniform` location. Vectors, matrices, and yes samplers and other opaque types all take up one location.

This is unlike vertex shader/fragment shader input/output variables.

Comment: So reading [this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)#Explicit_uniform_location) it says, _"All non-array/struct types will be assigned a single location."_  Is that the relevant citation?